# html focus inputs with BOTH tabbing and focus()

Tags: javascript, html, focus, accessibility, tabbing

Suppose I have

```
<input id="a" />
<a href="foo">foo</a>
<input id="b" />
```

By default tabbing will take me from `a` to `foo` to `b`. If I want to go from `a` to `b` directly I can do this

```
document .getElementById ("a") .setAttribute ("tabindex", 1);
document .getElementById ("b") .setAttribute ("tabindex", 2);
```

But now the following doesn't work because `focus()` apparently requires `tabindex=-1`

```
document .getElementById ("b") .focus ();
```

Can I have both?

Comment: Side note: Things may go better for you if you made sure your HTML is valid. Your inputs are missing a `type` attribute among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's started working all of a sudden, no idea what changed. Cached script perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what I'm seeing (Chrome). Pasting exactly what you have into http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/wW7Uy/

Puts the focus into the second text field and tabbing order is as expected (a->b->link)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your HTML to this:

```
<input id="a" tabindex = "1" />
<a href="foo" tabindex = "2">foo</a>
<input id="b" tabindex = "3" />
```

If you wanted the browser to skip `foo`, you would give it a tabindex of `-1`. `-1` tells the browser to not tabstop on that element.

Please let me know if I've missed something.